# XSD - Is possible to change attribute type in extension type

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to change the type of the `Name` attribute from `xs:string` to `xs:int`, like in XSD below

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://www.my.own/2013/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="AType">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="AType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:choice>
                        <xs:element name="Content" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Is this XSD valid? If not, is there exists other solutions to change type of attribute?

Comment: is that `Nane` in base `AType` typo?

Comment: What is your question Is it possible to change or is it valid?

Comment: 1. Typo fixed. 2. Actually I'm interested in answers for both questions

Comment: I thought it was possible using `<redefine>` element, apparently you can't override element declarations. Let's wait and see what others have to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the principle of type derivation is that if you derive a new type from a base type, the instances of the derived type must still be valid instances of the base type. So you can't change an attribute from string to int.